# Is there a name for this variant of the category of elements of a profunctor?

Tags: ct.category-theory, terminology, profunctors

Let $\mathsf{C}$ be a category and let $P : \mathsf{C}^{\text{op}} \times \mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{Set}$ be a functor.

Let $\mathsf{E}$ be the category whose:

- objects are pairs $(X,x)$, where $X$ is an object of $\mathsf{C}$ and $x \in P(X,X)$,
- morphisms $(X,x) \to (Y,y)$ are morphisms $f : X \to Y$ in $\mathsf{C}$ such that $f_* x = f^* y$,
- composition is inherited from $\mathsf{C}$.

This is a (non-full) subcategory of the category of elements of $P$, which appeared naturally [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4657284/19006).

Is there a standard name for this construction? Does $\mathsf{E}$ (and/or the forgetful functor $\mathsf{E} \to \mathsf{C}$) have any interesting properties to be aware of?

For example, here are some questions I have:

1. Suppose $\mathsf{C}$ is complete and $P$ is continuous. Must $\mathsf{E}$ be complete?
2. Must the forgetful functor $\mathsf{E} \to \mathsf{C}$ preserve limits?
3. When does the forgetful functor $\mathsf{E} \to \mathsf{C}$ have a left adjoint?

---

I'd also like to point out a couple of special cases:

1. If $\mathsf{C}$ is the category of topological spaces and $P$ is $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}$, then $\mathsf{E}$ is the category of (discrete) topological dynamical systems.
2. If $\mathsf{C}$ is the category of $R$-modules (for some commutative ring $R$) and $P$ is $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}$, then $\mathsf{E}$ is the category of $R[x]$-modules.

Comment: The case when $P=Hom_C$ can also be captured as $[\mathbb{N},C]$, in which case it has all the limits and colimits that $C$ has. Do you have other special cases of interest?

Comment: Good point, thanks! The link in my post is for the case $\mathsf{C} = \mathsf{Rng}$, $P = \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Set}}$, which apparently was of interest to someone. I suppose in this case $\mathsf{E} \to \mathsf{Rng}$ is the pullback of $[\mathbb{N}, \mathsf{Set}] \to \mathsf{Set}$ along $\mathsf{Rng} \to \mathsf{Set}$. I'm curious about this general setup just for curiosity's sake :)

Answer (score 3):

It *might* be enough to work out just the case of $P=\hom$!

I'll just leave an idea here since I don't have time to check it properly and I'll be glad if you took the fun away from me (you nerd-sniped me for a while!): $P$ gives rise to a category $C\uplus_PC$ called the [collage](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cograph+of+a+profunctor) or cograph of $P$, where elements of $P(x,y)$ have been rendered "true" morphisms from the "left" copy of $C$ to the "right" copy of $C$.

I think you can relate your category to $[\mathbb N, C\uplus_P C]$ (the cograph of $P=\hom$ is $C\times \{0\to 1\}$, right? And now $[\mathbb N, C\uplus_{\hom} C]=[\mathbb N, C\times \{0\le 1\}]\cong [\mathbb N, C]\times[\mathbb N,\{0\le 1\}]\cong [\mathbb N,C]$ because there are no nontrivial endomorphisms in $\{0\le1\}$), because an object $(X,x : P(X,X))$ is just an endomorphism (more precisely, and endo-[hetero-morphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/heteromorphism)) $x : X\to X$ in the collage.